# navigation drawer layout the title in the toolbar not changing

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer, toolbar

In the mTitle is not showing effect on the toolbar when a fragment is selected according to the fragment name specified in mTitle. It is just showing the app name in every fragment. please help!!!!

> MainActivity.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity
    implements NavigationDrawerFragment.NavigationDrawerCallbacks {

/**
 * Fragment managing the behaviors, interactions and presentation of the navigation drawer.
 */
private NavigationDrawerFragment mNavigationDrawerFragment;

/**
 * Used to store the last screen title. For use in {@link #restoreActionBar()}.
 */
private CharSequence mTitle;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mNavigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment)
            getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.navigation_drawer);
    mTitle = getTitle();

    // Set up the drawer.
    mNavigationDrawerFragment.setUp(
            R.id.navigation_drawer,
            (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout));
}

@Override
public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {

    Fragment fragment;
    //FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager(); // For AppCompat use getSupportFragmentManager
    switch(position) {
        default:
        case 0:
            fragment = new home();
            break;
        case 1:
            fragment = new academics();
            break;
        case 2:
            fragment = new about();
            break;
        case 3:
            fragment = new student();
            break;
        case 4:
            fragment = new alumini();
            break;
        case 5:
            fragment = new  events();
            break;
        case 6:
            fragment = new media();
            break;
        case 7:
            fragment = new contact();
            break;



    }
   /* fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.container,fragment )
            .commit();*/
    if (fragment != null) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container, fragment).commit();

    }






  /*  // update the main content by replacing fragments
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.container, PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1))
            .commit();*/
}

public void onSectionAttached(int number) {
    switch (number) {
        default:
        case 1:
            mTitle = getString(R.string.home);
            break;
        case 2:
            mTitle = getString(R.string.academics);
            break;
        case 3:
            mTitle = getString(R.string.about);
            break;
        case 4:
            mTitle = getString(R.string.student);
            break;
        case 5:
            mTitle = getString(R.string.alumni);
            break;
        case 6:
            mTitle = getString(R.string.events);
            break;
        case 7:
            mTitle = getString(R.string.media);
            break;
        case 8:
            mTitle = getString(R.string.contact);
            break;
    }
}

public void restoreActionBar() {
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setTitle(mTitle);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    if (!mNavigationDrawerFragment.isDrawerOpen()) {
        // Only show items in the action bar relevant to this screen
        // if the drawer is not showing. Otherwise, let the drawer
        // decide what to show in the action bar.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        restoreActionBar();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
    /**
     * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
     * fragment.
     */
    private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    /**
     * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
     * number.
     */
    public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
        PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        ((MainActivity) activity).onSectionAttached(
                getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER));
    }
}
```

}

> NavigationDrawerFragment.java

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

/**
 * Fragment used for managing interactions for and presentation of a     navigation drawer.
 * See the <a href="https://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation-drawer.html#Interaction">
 * design guidelines</a> for a complete explanation of the behaviors implemented here.
 */
 public class NavigationDrawerFragment extends Fragment {

/**
 * Remember the position of the selected item.
 */
private static final String STATE_SELECTED_POSITION = "selected_navigation_drawer_position";

/**
 * Per the design guidelines, you should show the drawer on launch until the user manually
 * expands it. This shared preference tracks this.
 */
private static final String PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER = "navigation_drawer_learned";

/**
 * A pointer to the current callbacks instance (the Activity).
 */
private NavigationDrawerCallbacks mCallbacks;

/**
 * Helper component that ties the action bar to the navigation drawer.
 */
private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
private ListView mDrawerListView;
private View mFragmentContainerView;

private int mCurrentSelectedPosition = 0;
private boolean mFromSavedInstanceState;
private boolean mUserLearnedDrawer;

public NavigationDrawerFragment() {
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Read in the flag indicating whether or not the user has demonstrated awareness of the
    // drawer. See PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER for details.
    SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
    mUserLearnedDrawer = sp.getBoolean(PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER, false);

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        mCurrentSelectedPosition = savedInstanceState.getInt(STATE_SELECTED_POSITION);
        mFromSavedInstanceState = true;
    }

    // Select either the default item (0) or the last selected item.
    selectItem(mCurrentSelectedPosition);
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    // Indicate that this fragment would like to influence the set of actions in the action bar.
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mDrawerListView = (ListView) inflater.inflate(
            R.layout.fragment_navigation_drawer, container, false);
    mDrawerListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            selectItem(position);
        }
    });
    mDrawerListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            getActionBar().getThemedContext(),
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1,
            android.R.id.text1,
            new String[]{
                    getString(R.string.home),
                    getString(R.string.academics),
                    getString(R.string.about),
                    getString(R.string.student),
                    getString(R.string.alumni),
                    getString(R.string.events),
                    getString(R.string.media),
                    getString(R.string.contact),

            }));
    mDrawerListView.setItemChecked(mCurrentSelectedPosition, true);
    return mDrawerListView;
}

public boolean isDrawerOpen() {
    return mDrawerLayout != null && mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mFragmentContainerView);
}

/**
 * Users of this fragment must call this method to set up the navigation drawer interactions.
 *
 * @param fragmentId   The android:id of this fragment in its activity's layout.
 * @param drawerLayout The DrawerLayout containing this fragment's UI.
 */
public void setUp(int fragmentId, DrawerLayout drawerLayout) {
    mFragmentContainerView = getActivity().findViewById(fragmentId);
    mDrawerLayout = drawerLayout;

    // set a custom shadow that overlays the main content when the drawer opens
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow, GravityCompat.START);
    // set up the drawer's list view with items and click listener

    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

    // ActionBarDrawerToggle ties together the the proper interactions
    // between the navigation drawer and the action bar app icon.
    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            getActivity(),                    /* host Activity */
            mDrawerLayout,                    /* DrawerLayout object */
            R.drawable.ic_drawer,             /* nav drawer image to replace 'Up' caret */
            R.string.navigation_drawer_open,  /* "open drawer" description for accessibility */
            R.string.navigation_drawer_close  /* "close drawer" description for accessibility */
    ) {
        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
            if (!isAdded()) {
                return;
            }

            getActivity().supportInvalidateOptionsMenu(); // calls onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            if (!isAdded()) {
                return;
            }

            if (!mUserLearnedDrawer) {
                // The user manually opened the drawer; store this flag to prevent auto-showing
                // the navigation drawer automatically in the future.
                mUserLearnedDrawer = true;
                SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager
                        .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
                sp.edit().putBoolean(PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER, true).apply();
            }

            getActivity().supportInvalidateOptionsMenu(); // calls onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        }
    };

    // If the user hasn't 'learned' about the drawer, open it to introduce them to the drawer,
    // per the navigation drawer design guidelines.
    if (!mUserLearnedDrawer && !mFromSavedInstanceState) {
        mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(mFragmentContainerView);
    }

    // Defer code dependent on restoration of previous instance state.
    mDrawerLayout.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mDrawerToggle.syncState();
        }
    });

    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
}

private void selectItem(int position) {
    mCurrentSelectedPosition = position;
    if (mDrawerListView != null) {
        mDrawerListView.setItemChecked(position, true);
    }
    if (mDrawerLayout != null) {
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mFragmentContainerView);
    }
    if (mCallbacks != null) {
        mCallbacks.onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(position);
    }
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    try {
        mCallbacks = (NavigationDrawerCallbacks) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException("Activity must implement NavigationDrawerCallbacks.");
    }
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    mCallbacks = null;
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putInt(STATE_SELECTED_POSITION, mCurrentSelectedPosition);
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    // Forward the new configuration the drawer toggle component.
    mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    // If the drawer is open, show the global app actions in the action bar. See also
    // showGlobalContextActionBar, which controls the top-left area of the action bar.
    if (mDrawerLayout != null && isDrawerOpen()) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.global, menu);
        showGlobalContextActionBar();
    }
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }

    if (item.getItemId() == R.id.action_example) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Example action.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/**
 * Per the navigation drawer design guidelines, updates the action bar to show the global app
 * 'context', rather than just what's in the current screen.
 */
private void showGlobalContextActionBar() {
    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
    actionBar.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
}

private ActionBar getActionBar() {
    return ((ActionBarActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar();
}

/**
 * Callbacks interface that all activities using this fragment must implement.
 */
public static interface NavigationDrawerCallbacks {
    /**
     * Called when an item in the navigation drawer is selected.
     */
    void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position);
}
}
```

> events.java   (one of the fragment java files )

```
 import android.app.Fragment;
 import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

/**
 * Created by sukhvir on 17/04/2015.    
*/
public class events extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {
public events(){}
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                         ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    /**
     * Inflate the layout for this fragment
     */
    return inflater.inflate(
            R.layout.events, container, false);
}
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public void onSectionAttached(int number) {
    switch (number) {
        default: //Default should not be here.
        case 1:
        mTitle = getString(R.string.home);
        break;
    ...
    case 8:
        mTitle = getString(R.string.contact);
        break;
    }
}
```

Fix the code above.

Your "events" Fragment class never calls onSectionAttached, this is a part of the implementation for the interface in PlaceholderFragment, which is created as a guideline. You should code your Fragments in a similar fashion and implement their corresponding interfaces.

Inside your Fragment:

> events.java

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

/**
 * Created by sukhvir on 17/04/2015.    
*/
public class events extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {
    public events(){}
    private static final int ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = 5;
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                         ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        /**
         * Inflate the layout for this fragment
         */
        return inflater.inflate(
            R.layout.events, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        ((MainActivity) activity).onSectionAttached(
            ARG_SECTION_NUMBER);
    }
}
```

and in:

> MainActivity.java

```
public void onSectionAttached(int number) {
switch (number) {
    case 1:
        mTitle = getString(R.string.home);
        break;
    case 2:
        mTitle = getString(R.string.academics);
        break;
    case 3:
        mTitle = getString(R.string.about);
        break;
    case 4:
        mTitle = getString(R.string.student);
        break;
    case 5:
        mTitle = getString(R.string.alumni);
        break;
    case 6:
        mTitle = getString(R.string.events);
        break;
    case 7:
        mTitle = getString(R.string.media);
        break;
    case 8:
        mTitle = getString(R.string.contact);
        break;
    }
    setTitle();
}

private void setTitle() {
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
}
```

I hope you get the idea.
The code above just works, you might want to understand the flow and clean up.

Comment: how should i  do that

Comment: it is showing modifier public not allowed here and modifier static not allowed here , is it possible ? could you figure it out  i tried everywhere buy was not able to find anything  @razzledazzle

Comment: @SukhvirThapar sorry, my mistake. :P

`private static final int ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = 5;` should be outside of onCreateView(), I've corrected the code.

Comment: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.os.Bundle.getInt(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference                getting this in logcat and the app is crashing when i select events. did the changes in the code you suggested  @razzledazzle